# Compare two files and find the difference

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv

I have two csv files, have to find difference for both files and generate the output file in sheet1 - difference data for txt1.csv and sheet2 - difference data for txt2.csv. Kindly advise me.

#### Sample Input :

txt1.csv

[image]

txt2.csv

[image]

#### Code

```
with open('txt1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('txt2.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)

with open('update1.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in fileone:
        if line not in filetwo:
            outFile.write(line)
```

### Expected output:

In sheet1
[image]

In sheet2
[image]

#### Note :

When the input file is too large above code is executing very slow

Comment: What happened or why does the solution doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.

**Dataset:**

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4],"B":[5,6,7,8]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2],"B":[2,9]})
```

**Output1:**

```
df1[~df1.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
    
    A
0   3
1   4
```

**Output2:**

```
df2[~df2.apply(tuple,1).isin(df1.apply(tuple,1))].reset_index(drop=True)

    A
0   8
1   9
```

---

In your case something like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("txt1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("txt2.csv")

delta1 = df1[~df1.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
delta2 = df2[~df2.apply(tuple,1).isin(df1.apply(tuple,1))].reset_index(drop=True)

delta1.to_csv("txt1_delta.csv", index=False)
delta2.to_csv("txt2_delta.csv", index=False)
```

edit, or if you want to have it in [Excel with multiple sheets](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html):

```
pip install xlsxwriter # if required

import xlsxwriter

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("your_output_excel.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
delta1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Delta1")
delta2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Delta2")

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```